# api data not displaying on html page

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am just trying to display the data from an API I built on my ionic app's hmtl, but the data is not showing up on the page for some reason.  When I call the data from the api in postman it show's as expected, as well as printing out when i call `console.log(data)` in the .ts file, but just doesn't show up on the webpage.  I am unclear as to what the problem is.

Below is my .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AllPatientsPage } from '../all-patients/all-patients';
import { RestService } from '../../providers/rest-service/rest-service';
import { ShareServiceProvider } from '../../providers/share-service/share-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-medHist',
  templateUrl: 'medHist.html'
})
export class MedHist {
   patientID: any;
   medicalHistory: any;
   obField: any;
   gynField: any;
   pmhField: any;
   pshField: any;
   medsField: any;
   allField: any;
   shField: any;

   constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, public shareService: ShareServiceProvider, public restService: RestService) {
      this.patientID = this.shareService.getSinglePatientID();
   }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.patientID = this.shareService.getSinglePatientID();
        console.log("patient testID");
        console.log(this.patientID);
        this.populatePage(this.patientID);
    }

    populatePage(id){
        console.log("single-test populate page testID");
        console.log(id);
        this.restService.getMedHist(id)
        .then(data => {
            console.log("patient data");
            console.log(data);
            this.medicalHistory = data;
            this.obField = this.medicalHistory.ob;
            this.gynField = this.medicalHistory.gyn;
            this.pmhField = this.medicalHistory.pmh;
            this.pshField = this.medicalHistory.psh;
            this.medsField = this.medicalHistory.meds;
            this.allField = this.medicalHistory.allVal;
            this.shField = this.medicalHistory.sh;
            console.log("data assigned");

        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        }); 
    }
}
```

below is the html:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid class="add-patient-border" text-left>
        <ion-row align-items: left>
            <ion-col col-auto>
                <ion-label> OB: </ion-label>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col style="max-width: 30%">
                <ion-input style="font-style: underline" readonly="true" [(ngModel)] = "obField"></ion-input>   
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row align-items: left>
            <ion-col col-auto>
                <ion-label> GYN: </ion-label>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-input readonly="true" [(ngModel)] = "gynField"></ion-input>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row align-items: left>
                        <ion-col col-auto>
                                <ion-label> PMH: </ion-label>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                                <ion-input readonly="true" [(ngModel)] = "pmhField"></ion-input>
                        </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
        <ion-row align-items: left>
                        <ion-col col-auto>
                                <ion-label> PSH: </ion-label>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                                <ion-input readonly="true" [(ngModel)] = "pshField"></ion-input>
                        </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
        <ion-row align-items: left>
                        <ion-col col-auto>
                                <ion-label> MEDS: </ion-label>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                                <ion-input readonly="true" [(ngModel)] = "medsField"></ion-input>
                        </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
        <ion-row align-items: left>
                        <ion-col col-auto>
                                <ion-label> ALL: </ion-label>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                                <ion-input readonly="true" [(ngModel)] = "allField"></ion-input>
                        </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
        <ion-row align-items: left>
                        <ion-col col-auto>
                                <ion-label> SH: </ion-label>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                                <ion-input readonly="true" [(ngModel)] = "shField"></ion-input>
                        </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

below is the rest-services provider class:

```
//below gets the medical history of a specific patient based on the patientID
getMedHist(id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('/getMedHist/' + id)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("rest-services.ts medHistory");
            this.data = data;
            console.log(this.data);
            resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: When you test it, what *do* you see in the console?

Comment: @ChrisG it prints out the data as expected like so: `{medHistID: 1, patientID: 1, ob: "sdjbka", gyn: "", pmh: "HTN, asthma"}` as well as the statement: `data assigned`

Comment: Which means the API call works fine. So debug the `this.obField = this.medicalHistory.ob;` lines; find out if they do what you think they do.

Comment: @ChrisG I have printed out the this.medicalHistory field and it still had the data, but when I log this.medicalHistory.ob it shows as undefined, any reason why this may be?

Comment: This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/7re49e4k/